# Powershell copy files based on last modified date & rename them afterwards

Tags: powershell

i´ve got little bit stucked with my powershell script.

I would like to run through multiple folders, grab files based on their last modified date and copy them to a new location.
There i have to rename them to a specific convention based on it´s original Filename.
What i wrote only runs through the first part and copy files successfully but not rename them afterwards. Of course when i run the script a second time it renames the files...

File convention is:
120_00001_000_002222_202201_20220124_121833_Formular - Copy.pdf

result should be
2222_120_Memory 01-2022_012022.pdf

this is what i got already

```
$path = "G:\Temp"
$Target = "K:\Local"
$Max_days = "-60" #Max Days past
$Curr_date = Get-Date
$files = get-childitem $Target *.pdf


Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter 120_*.pdf |
Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime `
        -gt (Get-Date $Curr_date.AddDays($Max_days)) `
             } | ForEach-Object { $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Target  -Force -PassThru } 

    foreach($pdf in $files)
 {
      $split = $pdf.name -replace ".pdf" -split "_"
      $newname = "$($split[3].TrimStart("0"))_$($split[0])_$("Memory") $($split[4].Substring($split[4].Length - 2, 2))-$($split[5].Substring(0,4))_$($split[4].Substring($split[4].Length - 2, 2))$($split[5].Substring(0,4))$($pdf.Extension)"
      write-verbose "Original: $($pdf.name)" -verbose
      write-verbose "NewName: $($newname)" -verbose
      Rename-Item $pdf.FullName -NewName $newname -verbose 
                }
```

Thanks in adavnced

Edited the Question to more precision.

Comment: Your code looks a bit messy if I may say so.. You can copy a file with a new name straight away, so there would be no reason to try and change the name afterwards. Also, since you are doing this `$files = get-childitem $Target *.pdf` up front, the file that gets copied there later will not be in collection `$files`. Please edit your question and give us a real life example of what the filename in the source is, and what the filename in the target path should eventually become.

Comment: Thanks for your answere @Theo
I ´m sorry that it could be a little bit messy to read.
The filename in the Source is what i already wrote.
120_00001_000_002222_202201_20220124_121833_Formular - Copy.pdf

The only thing is that there are multiple files in multiple subfolders which i want to copy to a new location and also give it a new naming convention.
result should be as written above.

So in simple thoughts i just grab all files from the folders and sub folders and copy them to the new target and rename them to the new convention afterwards.

Wrong thoughts ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you could do this in one loop and rename the file while copying.

Try below:

```
$path     = 'G:\Temp'
$Target   = 'K:\Local'
$Max_days = -60   # Max Days in the past
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays($Max_days).Date  # set to midnight

# get the files of interest
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter '120_*_*_*_*_*_*_*.pdf' -File |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    # rename the file to match the new file naming convention
    $split = $_.BaseName -split "_"
    # just for clarity, using this example: 
    # '120_00001_000_002222_202201_20220124_121833_Formular - Copy.pdf'

    # $split[0]  --> 120                used unchanged
    # $split[1]  --> 00001              unused
    # $split[2]  --> 000                unused
    # $split[3]  --> 002222             used without leading zeros
    # $split[4]  --> 202201             used, only the last two digits (month)
    # $split[5]  --> 20220124           used, only the first four digits (year)
    # $split[6]  --> 121833             unused
    # $split[7]  --> Formular - Copy    unused

    # these elements are used more than once, so for convenience store in separate variables
    $month = $split[4].Substring($split[4].Length - 2, 2)
    $year  = $split[5].Substring(0,4)

    # construct the new file name
    $newName = '{0}_{1}_Memory {2}-{3}_{2}{3}{4}' -f $split[3].TrimStart("0"),
                                                     $split[0],
                                                     $month,
                                                     $year,
                                                     $_.Extension
    # construct the complete target path and filename
    $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $Target -ChildPath $newName
    # now copy the file with a new name to the target folder
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile -Force
}
```

I've used the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) to construct the new filename, because I believe this makes the code easier to read.

I did not take into consideration that naming collisions might occur (file with that new name already in the target folder).
If that can happen, you need to tell us what strategy to use.
Perhaps append an index number to the file in brackets like Windows does?

Comment: Ah okay i Understand.

Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: The Files in the Target Folder will be used for further purpose so the Target will be empty when finished.